# Period time is too long

Tags: women, menses

This time my period is not going , 15 days are completed but the blood is still there, normally it is for 6 or 7 days , should I offer salah or should I just wait?

Comment: When you ask a question stackexchange already show you choices for similar ones this question already has answers on the site. We are not looking for question duplicates. In fact one of these questions is your own and the answer came from the same person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the period should be finished by the 15th day or before that so anything that exceeds 15 days would count as Istihadah. Istihadah is non-menstrual or irregular bleeding and basically if you suffer from this you can do ghusl and then pray or fast as usual.  You would still need to do wudhu before each prayer. If you need more information:
https://youtu.be/LjYy4azvDcU

Allah knows best.

Comment: But it is never happened to me before, so will it count as istihadah?

Comment: Yes it would still count

Comment: Btw thanks jazakallah ☺️